# Want to delete Ubuntu 9 from a dual partition system with Vista

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, grub

I have Windows Vista and Ubuntu 9 co-installed  on my dual partition system. The boot is controlled by GNU Grub.  How can I **safely** uninstall and completely delete Ubuntu and recycle the disk space to be used by Vista that remains. I have extremely important data on Vista, so I cannot afford an error in the process. Any help  will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do.

- First, Log into Ubuntu and back up
  all the data from the Home directory
  that you need.
- Then Log into Vista, and delete the
  Ubuntu Partition. you can do this by
  going to  Start > Rt Click on
  Computer > Select Manage Then in the
  left hand pane, under Storage
  category, click on Disk Management
  Now select and right click on the
  partition you wish to delete.  You
  can then also delete the swap if you
  have it. See this page for more
  details:
  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Delete-a-hard-disk-partition
- After this, you need to fix the Master boot record. You can follow the steps given here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Please note that you require your Vista DVD to fix the MBR.